# Excel formula to Google Sheets formula with "" inside the formular

Tags: javascript, excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script which opens an excel sheet from Google Drive to take some Values from it. The problem I have is, that some formulas do not get converted. So I do .setValue("Formula") to update the formula. In the excel is one formular where this does not work, because inside the formula are the apostrophes ("") used.

This is the formular I want to use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Query!$K$2:$K$20863=$E$28)*(RIGHT(Query!$A$2:$A$20863;3)<>"001")*(Query!$G$2:$G$20863))
```

The .setValue code:

```
SpreadsheetApp.openById(newID).getSheetByName("Linie 16").getRange(28,3,1,1).setValue("=SUMMENPRODUKT((Query!$K$2:$K$20876=$E$28)*(RECHTS(Query!$A$2:$A$20876;3)<>"001")*(Query!$G$2:$G$20876)));
```

Is there a way around this?

Thanks in advance,
Sammi :)

Comment: you can replace the double quotes with single quotes `setValue('=SUMMENPRODUKT((Query!$K$2:$K$20876=$E$28)*(RECHTS(Query!$A$2:$A$20876;3)<>"001")*(Query!$G$2:$G$20876))')` and leave the double quotes in the formula itself

Comment: Haha I tried the exact same, but only for the apostrophes inside the formular. Thanks it worked!